# How to make collision in HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, collision, minecraft

I'm making a game in JavaScript HTML5 Canvas. It is a 2D Minecraft-like game, but I can't figure out collision detection...
I have asked my brother for help, but he doesn't know how to
make collision detection in HTML5 Canvas JavaScript.
If someone can help me, I will be very grateful.

This is my game code:

```
var g = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
setInterval(update, 1000/100);

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    delete keys[e.keyCode];
});

var keys = [];

var player = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    isFalling: true,
};

var up = true;
var left = true;
var right = true;

var w = 10;
var h = 10;

var block_size = 20;

var m = {};

for(var x = 0; x < w; x++) {
    m[x] = {};
    for(var y = 0; y < w; y++) {
        m[x][y] = "sky";
    }
}

generateWorld();

function isColl(x1,y1,w1,h1,x2,y2,w2,h2) {
    return(x1 <= x2 && x1+w1 >= x2 && y1 <= y2 && y1+h1 >= y2 || x2 <= x1 && x2+w2 >= x1 && y2 <= y1 && y2+h2 >= y1);           
}

function update() {
    g.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";
    g.fillRect(0,0,200,200);

    var dx = player.x/block_size;
    var dy = player.y/block_size;

    for(var x = 0; x < w; x++) {
        for(var y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            if(m[x][y] == "grass") {
                g.fillStyle = "rgb(0,200,0)";
                g.fillRect(x*20,y*20,20,20);
            } else if(m[x][y] == "sky") {
                g.fillStyle = "rgb(100,100,255)";
                g.fillRect(x*20,y*20,20,20);
            } else if(m[x][y] == "dirt") {
                g.fillStyle = "rgb(100,40,0)";
                g.fillRect(x*20,y*20,20,20);
            } else if(m[x][y] == "grass") {
                g.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,255)";
                g.fillRect(x*20,y*20,20,20);
            } else {
                g.fillStyle = "rgb(200,50,200)";
                g.fillRect(x*20,y*20,20,20);
                g.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
                g.fillText("404", (x*20), (y*20)+15);
            }
        }
    }

    g.fillStyle = "rgb(255,50,0)";
    g.fillRect(player.x,player.y,20,20);

    if(keys[38] && player.y > 0 && up) {
        player.y--;
        player.isFalling = false;
    } else {
        player.isFalling = true;
    }
    if(keys[39] && player.x < 180 && right) {
        player.x++;
    }
    if(keys[37] && player.x > 0 && left) {
        player.x--;
    }   
    if(player.isFalling && player.y < 180) {
        player.y++;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help you a lot:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: i don't understood!,
I'm getting started with JavaScript Canvas HTML5.
i tried to adapt the code to my game but don't worked...

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways of doing this.

1. Consider all of your objects as spheres and check if the distance between objects are below the radius of the said spheres.

Example:

```
function checkCollision_Sph(centerX,centerY,radius,centerX_2,centerY_2,radius_2){
distance = Math.sqrt((centerX_2 - centerX)^2 + (centerY_2 - centerY)^2)
if(distance <= (radius+radius_2)){ 
//Distance between spheres is less than the sum of theirs radius, colliding!
}
```

2. Consider all of your objects as rectangles and check if the rectangle's bounding boxes are overlapping each other.

Example:

```
function checkCollision_Rec(x1,w1,y1,h1,x2,w2,y2,h2){
//x1, x2           = Left
//x1 + w1, x2 + w2 = Right
//y1, y2           = Bottom
//y1 - h1, y2 - h2 = Top


if((y1 < y2)     || 
  ((y1 - h1) > y2) ||
   (x1 > (x2 + w2)) ||
  ((x1 + w1) < x2)
){
//Is not colliding!
}
else{
//Is colliding!
}
```

I found a good page that has similar examples that might help you to figure it out: [Basic collision detection in 2d](http://devmag.org.za/2009/04/13/basic-collision-detection-in-2d-part-1/)